# gcc -O3 removing live code in int-to-string converter

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I was 64-bit-izing [Terje Mathisen's itoa function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32818030/9781227), which takes a `char*` which must point to a buffer of at least 20 characters and a number, and I created this:

```
#define LOOP_WORK(number, shift) high *= 5; low *= 5; buf[number] = (high >> shift) + '0'; \
    buf[number+10] = (low >> shift) + '0'; high &= andop; low &= andop; andop >>= 1

#define uint128_t __uint128_t
#define uint64_t  unsigned long

void u2s(char* buf, unsigned long num) {
    // Split number into low/high pair.
    uint128_t split = num * 7922816251426433760;
    split += num >> 1;
    uint64_t high = split >> 96;
    uint64_t low = num - (high * 10000000000);
    // Transform numbers into usable decimal fractions.
    split = high * 18446744074;
    buf[0]  = (split >> 64) + '0';
    high = (uint64_t)split;
    split = low  * 18446744074;
    buf[10] = (split >> 64) + '0';
    low  = (uint64_t)split;
    // Adjust numbers and multiply by 2 (so we don't have to multiply by 10 later)
    high = (high + 7) >> 3;
    low  = (low  + 7) >> 3;
    // Store special and number
    uint64_t andop = 0x0fffffffffffffff;
    LOOP_WORK(1, 60);
    LOOP_WORK(2, 59);
    LOOP_WORK(3, 58);
    LOOP_WORK(4, 57);
    LOOP_WORK(5, 56);
    LOOP_WORK(6, 55);
    LOOP_WORK(7, 54);
    LOOP_WORK(8, 53);
    // Final loop, without extra stuffs
    high *= 5;
    low  *= 5;
    buf[9]  = (high >> 52) + '0';
    buf[19] = (low  >> 52) + '0';
}

#undef LOOP_WORK
```

Here's an equivalent version in assembly (handwritten in AT&T):

```
u2s:
    // tmp128(rax:rdx) = num * 7922816251426433760
    movq $7922816251426433760, %rax
    mulq %rsi
    // tmp128(rax:rdx) += num >> 1
    movq %rsi, %rcx
    shrq $0x1, %rcx
    addq %rcx, %rax
    adcq $0x0, %rdx
    // high(rdx) = tmp128(rax:rdx) >> 96
    shrq $32,  %rdx
    // high(rcx); low(rsi) = num - (high * 10^10)
    movq %rdx, %rcx
    movq $10000000000, %rax
    mulq %rdx
    subq %rax, %rsi
    // high2(rax:rdx) = high * 18446744074
    movq $18446744074, %rax
    mulq %rcx
    // buf[0] = (high2 >> 64) + '0'
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  (%rdi)
    // low2(rax:rdx) = low * 18446744074
    movq %rax, %rcx
    movq $18446744074, %rax
    mulq %rsi
    // buf[10] = (low2 >> 64) + '0'
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  10(%rdi)
    // high(rcx) = (u64)high2
    // low(rax)  = (u64)low2
    // high = (high + 7) >> 3
    addb $0x7, %cl
    shrq $0x3, %rcx
    // low  = (low  + 7) >> 3
    addb $0x7, %al
    shrq $0x3, %rax
    // low (rax) *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // high(rcx) *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // buf[1]  = (high >> 60) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $60,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  1(%rdi)
    // buf[11] = (low  >> 60) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $60,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  11(%rdi)
    // Store number 0x0fffffffffffffff
    movq $0x0fffffffffffffff, %rsi
    // high &= 0x0fffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x0fffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[2]  = (high >> 59) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $59,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  2(%rdi)
    // buf[12] = (low  >> 59) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $59,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  12(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x07ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x07ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[3]  = (high >> 58) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $58,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  3(%rdi)
    // buf[13] = (low  >> 58) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $58,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  13(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x03ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x03ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[4]  = (high >> 57) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $57,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  4(%rdi)
    // buf[14] = (low  >> 57) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $57,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  14(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x01ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x01ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[5]  = (high >> 56) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $56,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  5(%rdi)
    // buf[15] = (low  >> 56) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $56,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  15(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x00ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x00ffffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[6]  = (high >> 55) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $55,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  6(%rdi)
    // buf[16] = (low  >> 55) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $55,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  16(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x007fffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x007fffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[7]  = (high >> 54) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $54,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  7(%rdi)
    // buf[17] = (low  >> 54) + '0'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $54,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  17(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x003fffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x003fffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[8]  = (high >> 53) + '0'
    movq %rcx, %rdx
    shrq $53,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  8(%rdi)
    // buf[18] = (low  >> 53) + '0e'
    movq %rax, %rdx
    shrq $53,  %rdx
    addb $'0', %dl
    movb %dl,  18(%rdi)
    // update the `and` number
    shrq $0x1, %rsi
    // high &= 0x001fffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rcx
    // low  &= 0x001fffffffffffff
    andq %rsi, %rax
    // high *= 5
    leaq (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    // low  *= 5
    leaq (%rax,%rax,4), %rax
    // buf[9]  = (high >> 52) + '0'
    shrq $52,  %rcx
    addb $'0', %cl
    movb %cl,  9(%rdi)
    // buf[19] = (high >> 52) + '0'
    shrq $52,  %rax
    addb $'0', %al
    movb %al,  19(%rdi)
    retq
```

When I compile the C version in GCC with optimizations `-O3`, I find that code for one of the high/low variables is optimized out, it has hardcoded values for `andop` everywhere, and the code at the start to load in `buf[0]` and `buf[10]` inputs hard-coded values (`48` and `3472328296227680304`, respectively). When I run GCC with `-fverbose-asm -S`, I find that GCC optimized away `high` completely! I'm guessing that my C code's the problem (I'm not too great at C), but I don't know why. [Terje Mathisen's post](http://computer-programming-forum.com/46-asm/7aa4b50bce8dd985.htm) has it's own version in C, but it does not include the handwritten assembly optimizations also given there. Why is GCC messing me up so much?

B.T.W, here's the code from `gcc (Gentoo 7.3.0-r1 p1.1) 7.3.0` (USE flags: `-cilk +cxx -debug -doc +fortran -go -graphite -mpx -nls +nptl -objc -objc++ -objc-gc +openmp +pch -pgo +pie -regression-test +sanitize +ssp -vanilla +vtv`) with flags `-O3 -c` (an objdump with flags `-d`):

```
u2s.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <u2s>:
   0:   48 b8 0a fa 82 4b 04    movabs $0x44b82fa0a,%rax
   7:   00 00 00 
   a:   48 b9 30 30 30 30 30    movabs $0x3030303030303030,%rcx
  11:   30 30 30 
  14:   c6 47 0a 30             movb   $0x30,0xa(%rdi) // What?
  18:   48 0f af f0             imul   %rax,%rsi
  1c:   48 89 0f                mov    %rcx,(%rdi) // What?
  1f:   48 83 c6 07             add    $0x7,%rsi
  23:   48 c1 ee 03             shr    $0x3,%rsi
  27:   48 8d 04 b6             lea    (%rsi,%rsi,4),%rax
  2b:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  2e:   48 c1 ea 3c             shr    $0x3c,%rdx
  32:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  35:   88 57 0b                mov    %dl,0xb(%rdi)
  38:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0xfffffffffffffff,%rdx
  3f:   ff ff 0f 
  42:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax // There should be another AND
  45:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  49:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  4c:   48 c1 ea 3b             shr    $0x3b,%rdx
  50:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  53:   88 57 0c                mov    %dl,0xc(%rdi)
  56:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x7ffffffffffffff,%rdx
  5d:   ff ff 07 
  60:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  63:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  67:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  6a:   48 c1 ea 3a             shr    $0x3a,%rdx
  6e:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  71:   88 57 0d                mov    %dl,0xd(%rdi)
  74:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x3ffffffffffffff,%rdx
  7b:   ff ff 03 
  7e:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  81:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  85:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  88:   48 c1 ea 39             shr    $0x39,%rdx
  8c:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  8f:   88 57 0e                mov    %dl,0xe(%rdi)
  92:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x1ffffffffffffff,%rdx
  99:   ff ff 01 
  9c:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  9f:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  a3:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  a6:   48 c1 ea 38             shr    $0x38,%rdx
  aa:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  ad:   88 57 0f                mov    %dl,0xf(%rdi)
  b0:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0xffffffffffffff,%rdx
  b7:   ff ff 00 
  ba:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  bd:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  c1:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  c4:   48 c1 ea 37             shr    $0x37,%rdx
  c8:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  cb:   88 57 10                mov    %dl,0x10(%rdi)
  ce:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x7fffffffffffff,%rdx
  d5:   ff 7f 00 
  d8:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  db:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  df:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  e2:   48 c1 ea 36             shr    $0x36,%rdx
  e6:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
  e9:   88 57 11                mov    %dl,0x11(%rdi)
  ec:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x3fffffffffffff,%rdx
  f3:   ff 3f 00 
  f6:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  f9:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
  fd:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 100:   48 c1 ea 35             shr    $0x35,%rdx
 104:   83 c2 30                add    $0x30,%edx
 107:   88 57 12                mov    %dl,0x12(%rdi)
 10a:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x1fffffffffffff,%rdx
 111:   ff 1f 00 
 114:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
 117:   ba 30 30 00 00          mov    $0x3030,%edx
 11c:   48 8d 04 80             lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%rax
 120:   66 89 57 08             mov    %dx,0x8(%rdi)
 124:   48 c1 e8 34             shr    $0x34,%rax
 128:   83 c0 30                add    $0x30,%eax
 12b:   88 47 13                mov    %al,0x13(%rdi)
 12e:   c3                      retq
```

P.S: I've tested my handwritten assembly well, and so most differences between that and the `objdump` are mostly either code reordering or errors.

P.P.S: @Peter_Corde's answer has prevented the optimization-away of `high`, but the starting code is still messed up! Here's an excerpt:

```
   0:   48 b9 e0 ea f6 5e 67    movabs $0x6df37f675ef6eae0,%rcx
   7:   7f f3 6d 
   a:   49 b8 00 e4 0b 54 02    movabs $0x2540be400,%r8
  11:   00 00 00 
  14:   c6 07 30                movb   $0x30,(%rdi) // NOT GOOD
  17:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  1a:   48 89 f1                mov    %rsi,%rcx
  1d:   c6 47 0a 30             movb   $0x30,0xa(%rdi) // NOT GOOD
  21:   48 f7 e6                mul    %rsi
  24:   48 d1 e9                shr    %rcx
  27:   49 89 c1                mov    %rax,%r9
  2a:   48 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%rax
  2d:   49 89 d2                mov    %rdx,%r10
  30:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
  32:   4c 01 c8                add    %r9,%rax
  35:   48 b9 0a fa 82 4b 04    movabs $0x44b82fa0a,%rcx
  3c:   00 00 00 
  3f:   4c 11 d2                adc    %r10,%rdx
  42:   48 c1 ea 20             shr    $0x20,%rdx
  46:   48 89 d0                mov    %rdx,%rax
  49:   49 0f af d0             imul   %r8,%rdx
  4d:   48 0f af c1             imul   %rcx,%rax
  51:   48 29 d6                sub    %rdx,%rsi
  54:   48 0f af f1             imul   %rcx,%rsi
  58:   48 83 c0 07             add    $0x7,%rax
  5c:   48 c1 e8 03             shr    $0x3,%rax
```

Comment: Is `split = high * 18446744074;` supposed to be `split = high * (unsigned __int128)18446744074;`?  Looks like *exactly* the same bug.  Check the rest of your C code for any more cases where you assign the result of a calculation to a wider variable.

Comment: You're right! It's fixed! Thanks. Can you make the comment an answer, or add to your previous answer?

Comment: BTW, about your 2nd comment, we later ignore the high bits of `split`. We only use the low bits. Test out the program! In my tests, I was only getting an output of 0 because `strtoull` was being passed `argv[0]` instead of `argv[1]` *facepalm*. Well, it's sorted out now!

Comment: done, although really my answer already pointed out the bug you're having.  Finding every instance of that bug in the code you posted is a minor detail (for future readers with the same problem in different code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when the compiler shows you that some of your function outputs unexpectedly don't depend on the input, that's usually a sign that your C source doesn't mean what you thought it did.

In this case it looks like `uint128_t split = num * 7922816251426433760;` is the problem.  `num` is an `unsigned long` (`uint64_t` in the x86-64 SysV ABI which you're compiling for).  Thus, the `*` operator produces a 64-bit result which is zero-extended as an initializer for `uint128_t split`.

```
uint128_t split = (unsigned __int128) num * 7922816251426433760;
```

casts `num` to a 128-bit integer before the multiply, so you get a full 128-bit result with `mulq`.  ([gcc7.3 -O3 on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMWAGZ4WmANQAZAPKaACgH0A6poBKAaQgsRAWwBGmMqsEI8CggEpVz4AlUAqDrIAIqoArAE8qgyoAO5%2BAcFhshE2IgocITyWtvbpwfGqEF4%2BAdgljs6uHvyqYFIADLXhqukAwhx1AIKq3aopaRlZdsT8tHW5zUEFUbElZU4u7s28NfWNSZ543ksAbPms6KgADk3TO3ssB8fr%2B0cTpbL3wbTtHS9yispqIsoEtFwAHHoCKo9HpvixfgCgW8uPJMEoVKpwQRtgAWIHdEQsQSbFToSKoNhvToAN1QeHxIi4gggyAQTGIvl6qVISOxuMw%2BKibFUWSqAHY%2BJ0eqoAPSi1QAZUODEIvOsQ1UP1QBOioqKqkOTDwxAAdC8Rci/oDgYIZXL8hAsTjgHiQXofsaPFk/Kp%2BQBOLgA2jbLghWiorho2SyfnbMZJA09M2y4H8fIu2YPVTPSPCnrItEYjX5GMWh5ld27NNdDM/LPA04J6yqAC0BQ1TNGdRbrdbbnCUe64tUABViKxBAoSFZ5dliIIlRCVSJBEwbAw1FhkHgrEwGKoFAPkAQ8ITBPr09083HJo2U/9Uajtvyr3Vb52j8z%2BjwxiFghNghAT3cymiqsstQNDIJYijmkxWuW6LuCej6lse5qnsEpyurQl7XreqL3qicEin06Q8KM4yWj%2BSbYKo/5LBEQFrEK8Gqt0lqZtBbiwaBPQ9h06BULOwKDPYk77KoVgiAwu4ygAnr0UlcAUwiqNES6ErUwL0iSahEMJoniQwUk2FJoyREwBD2B2T7gV%2BObLPyVQFsmsi4T0KGWs51m2fc5EOex3YSpKRDEGoZqYCu66qEJ/HDE%2BzEYjchyfqodQAB51AoqVpelGWOd0Wi6IYJjmPQFF1B23kaNo%2BhGGYEBcKyITuiVdEijlFX5RAsi1f8DVdmVuWVeYqK1TZWU9S1VUhLV2xdU%2BzV5VV2y1SEU30TNfUQPytWoktTXlbN5j/LVshbRxEoAGLKKFURHKy0SEAgojApgiUEAOjgEKkCiCN1jb5IkjVOTE3T%2BJMv3dfhGTuuM8WFJsxR2eRIRcAB1GrCBf3dGDhEQ%2B%2BUPOXDoSI1RKzAXBHD8oExKvLCWKKCNu1SG4jDSCEUikCw0h1CzqDSG0vDVMIYgSEssi0CzBDs/TDMANYgCEIS6rQtD8qGdT/J6dRofy%2B0MNIqIs2z9Sc9ILOCCAdSkGLBsM3AsBIGgViHHgi5kBQtKoPbjv2CAwBK6QShiQJlA2OLpA2OdxASdIIukHbViYBCmgsLpwdYGubCLsnOrBbu6kmwbpCPcFIgmZHLM/Jg2tSFHz2riXDPMGwKDxrwjB4DYJuQAzRy7vu0i1olyB1gY64brWggEOg8S2iICt1posjG6I4iSLQddM3rwdc1IiX/NstZoqowDIAP/K6rIBS4IQJBC4VLRuw7TvXx4PN8Lwovi24DMIJgTBYMQlBSyAK8up/j/CDFwd0owPT/D%2BDVCuutSBWDoC2VmG8jZCFNubd%2Bq8pBcHXnnTeb9LYM3UhOPcbNURAA%3D%3D)).

I didn't look into the full details of the rest of your function; there may be other problems, but that's the first one I saw.

---

re: update:

Is `split = high * 18446744074;` supposed to be `split = high * (unsigned __int128)18446744074;`? Looks like exactly the same bug. Check the rest of your C code for any more cases where you assign the result of a calculation to a wider variable.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the main issue of `high` being optimized away! But the starter code is still messed up. Thanks a lot, though!

Comment: BTW, shouldn't GCC complain about this? I tried compiling my code with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` but nothing showed up. How come?

Comment: @ARaspiK: You're allowed to have arithmetic overflow on unsigned types with no consequences, so the 64-bit unsigned multiplication with overflow was legitimate.  The compiler assumed you meant what you said.

Comment: @ARaspiK: You're wishing that gcc would warn that `uint64_t high = split >> 96;` was an over-complicated way of writing `high=0`?  In this case that's a bug, but in other cases, especially after inlining, the same logic could be a desirable optimization when two separate functions end up interacting this way.  Or it could be from a macro, which the compiler itself can't see, so even when the code is in the same function it might be inappropriate to warn.  The closest thing I see is `-Wtype-limits` which will warn about `unsigned u=...;  if (u < 0)` or `if(u>UINT_MAX)`.

Comment: A warning option like that might be useful for localized debugging in cases like this, but gcc doesn't have such an option (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).  I didn't check clang.  Normally you'd just single-step with a debugger and notice that `high=0`, and get back to the problem line right away.  Looking at the asm output and working backwards to see that `high=0` was a compile-time constant is another way to see the same thing, which is what I did.

Comment: In addition to the ways Peter mentioned, template code results in all sorts of scenarios where you legitimately end up with dead code, expressions that are always zero, etc. So many of the "why are you doing this?" type warnings the compiler could produce become added noise when using templates.